# How to use swagger-ui-express.serve and setup swagger document inside call back function Nodejs

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-node

```
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerDocument = require('./swagger.json');

app.use('/swagger', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));
```

instead of this, i want to use inside callback function of NodeJS
Need to set basepath dynamically inside callback function.

```
app.use('/swagger', function(req,res) {
  swaggerDocument.basepath = "/pet/details",
  res.send(swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));
});
```

Please help me to resolve this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution,

Used callback function like this,

```
router.use(
 swaggerUi.serve,
 function(req, res) {
   swaggerDocument.host = req.get('host'); // Replace hardcoded host information in swagger file
   swaggerDocument.schemes = [req.protocol]; // Replace hardcoded protocol information in Swagger file
   swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument)(req, res);
 }
});
```

Comment: Hi, did this work ? I am trying similar thing except that the swaggerDocument is in itself chosen inside the callback based on the URL. I get it working one time and the other time it does not, I really cannot get a grip on it. Do you have any suggestions ?